# mac osx recent items even if i change it from the preferences like 5 it resets it to none again

Tags: xcode, macos, recent-file-list, recent-documents

OS X El capitan, i realised that i can not see any recent projects especially in the Xcode. Then i made some search and i found that i could change that option from the System Preferences. When i change the recent items count from none to 5 for instance, when i close the preferences window and go there again i see that the items 5 has changed to the none option again. I tried some of plist file deletions from the Library/Preferences i saw in some sites but it did not help. I am not able to find any solution for that. So how can i change this option permanently?

Comment: You could try using the defaults command in Terminal to edit Xcode's preferences. (Perhaps quit Xcode first.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/219763/recent-items-count-is-not-saved-in-system-preferences-os-x-10-11-el-capitan) go with this steps:

1. Open `Terminal` and execute command

   `rm ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.recentitems.plist`
2. Restart mac
3. Now your mac will save setted number of recent items